# What house plant this is?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, planting

My wife picked up this plant and it didnt had a tag , though it looks beautiful.

[image]

I have noticed it doesn't take much water and going fine in less light unlike the basil plant lying nearby dries faster and needs more light. If I know what plant this is then I want to know how should I take care of this plant and how much light it requires.

Comment: Did you notice a specific scent? Minty, perhaps?

Comment: How tall is that plant?

Comment: Btw., it’s not “fine” with the amount of light it receives - look at the long stems between the sets of leaves and how much it leans towards the window.